# Retrieve previous tak definition and prepare new task definition - Could not connect to endpoint https://ecs.********.amazonws.com/

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

can you help me?
I'm doing a continuous deployment with circle.ci...
The unity tests, build and push is working.

But when i try update the ecs task, i'm getting the error:[image]

*ERROR: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: https://ecs.********.amazonws.com/*

in the circle.ci i'm using the orbs
aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@2.2.1

[image]

Any idea what is happen?
I don't know what to think/search anymore..

## Update:

I tried run the command
**aws ecs update-service --service ng-prod-service --cluster ng-cluster --force-new-deployment**
And to  my surprise i get the same error..

But my aws login works..
**aws ecr get-login-password --region sa-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 119120169187.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com**

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with my credentials...
So i made new credentials with new iam rules and registerd on circle.ci and then it works...
It was probably the iam rules or iam credentials...